# How to solve "undefined method `element_present?' for main:Object (NoMethodError) Ruby Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am now trying to Selenium UnitTest with Ruby

And as I research to recognize the element exist or not by using element_present, however, the error illustrates that it is not defined.

How can I fix this error, if you know well, please advice me.

test3.rb↓

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "http://localhost:8080/en"
driver.find_element(:id, 'search').send_keys("Bask")
driver.find_element(:id, 'TMbtn').click


if element_present?(:id, 'create') == true
    driver.find_element(:id, 'create').click
    driver.save_screenshot('tabetai2.png')
else
    driver.save_screenshot('tabetai3.png')
end
sleep 5
driver.quit
```

Error↓(Terminal)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
test3.rb:8:in `<main>': undefined method `element_present?' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method to check whether element exist or not in selenium. You can know only after error occurs. You can write the following code internally to check whether element exist or not.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "https://spiritualteacher.proboards.com/"

def element_present(driver, locator)
  flag = true
  begin
    driver.find_element(locator.split("=").first.strip.to_sym => locator.split("=").last.strip)
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError => e
    flag = false
  end
  flag
end

#Taken an element which doesn't exist
if element_present(driver, "id=something")
  puts 'element present'
else
  puts 'element not present'
end
#Taken an element which exist
if element_present(driver, "css=.state-active")
  puts 'element present'
else
  puts 'element not present'
end
```

Remember, If you are using implicit wait, then you have to make it zero before you check the element, after you checked that element you have to re-assign that timing back to your implicit wait. If you don't, checking will be using your implicit wait which should not be the case.